# Can we add more files into the build directory if we have not installed the python module yet?

Tags: python

The python documentation states that we can build and install a python module separately. What benefit does it provide? Does it mean that we can add more files to the build directory if we have not installed the module(thought the module has been built)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python module/package is for distributing a code, not data

Building modules or packages is creating different types of distribution formats. Some of them being:

- python source code - for pure python apps, sort or ZIP archive, extension `zip` or `tar.gz`
- egg - zip archive with whatever can be compiled being compiled - extension `egg`
- exe - Windows installation package
- whl - wheel - compiled package distribution package
- etc.

Do not confuse using distribution package with a mean for providing some data for an application. While it is possible and sometime used to provide static data as part of a distribution package, you shall never include changing data as part of your package as it conflicts with the fact, the package is installed on one place and can be simultaneously used by multiple application.

## Adding files to build directory

In general, your build shall manage all the content on it's own and shall not expect modifying the distribution package. Forget about this kind of tricks and you will safe a lot of headache.